# Improve HTML styling of Pandas DataFrames within IPython widgets

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

How can I generate appropriate HTML to hand to an `ipywidgets.HTML` object to properly display a Pandas DataFrame?

[image]

Comment: From where do you import VBox?

Comment: `from ipywidgets import VBox`. It looks like they export all their widgets there, since they use `from ipywidgets import *` in the docs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be achieved with the lovely new [`DataFrame.style`](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/pydata/pandas/blob/master/doc/source/html-styling.ipynb) class.

For example

[image]

This example depends on bootstrap's CSS being loaded on the page. It's included in the notebook when you're running the notebook interactively.

More generally a mixture of `set_table_attributes` to give it a class, and `set_table_styles` for more specific items should give pretty fine-grained controls.

Comment: Oh, and it looks like `x` was cast to a float (it wasn't really). This has been fixed in master.